# Decrypt local file using Azure Decryption

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

I encrypt a file using a key from KeyVault and upload blob in Azure storage.

Now, I download this same encrypted file from the portal on my local machine and want to decrypt this file using C# console application.

Is there any API from Azure that can be used for this purpose? If yes, please guide.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any API from Azure that can be used for this purpose? If yes, please guide.

Based on my experience, **no**.  In your case, you download the encrypted file from the portal. There is no related wrapped CEK and IV to decrypted data. How to  decrypt blob and download, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault#encrypt-blob-and-upload).

> **During encryption**, the client library will **generate a random Initialization Vector (IV) of 16 bytes**, **together with a random content encryption key (CEK) of 32 bytes**, and perform envelope encryption of the blob data using this information. The wrapped CEK and some additional encryption metadata are then stored as blob metadata along with the encrypted blob on the service.
>
> **During decryption**,  the wrapped CEK is unwrapped and used together with the IV (stored as blob metadata in this case) to return the decrypted data

Comment: Thanks for your response.